# Lower part of the screen not responding to touch

Tags: lg-g2, external-display, water-damage

While I was holding my LG G2 when running, sweat got into the lower right corner under the screen, leading to the lower part of the screen (about one third inches) not responding to touch. The phone can power on without any problem, and there is no problem with the display either, but I can't access to the navigation buttons (home, back, etc) and the app drawer button because that part of the screen is not responsive. I sent it to LG for warranty repair, but they returned the phone as is, claiming "liquid damage, not repairable".

My question is: Is the phone really not repairable as LG claimed? Is the damage only on the screen? Can I just buy a display / digitizer assembly and replace the screen myself?

Comment: Have you tried any soft-key apps like the [Back button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.app58us.backkey) or [Navigation Bars](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kimcy92.navigationbar)?

Comment: @Lucky Thanks, that would help a little, but would not solve the problem. For example, the lower part of the keyboard is still not usable.